# How is a Java Project Structured (Compared to a Visual Studio C# Project)?

Tags: java, visual-studio, netbeans

I'm trying to learn project automation and I'm using the book [Pragmatic Project Automation](http://pragprog.com/book/auto/pragmatic-project-automation) as a guide. It's examples are in Java so I find it easier to follow it along in Java. I don't have any experience using Java or any of its IDEs. However, I've learned some C# using Visual Studio (although I'm still a beginner).

I'm having trouble understanding some parts of setting up a Java project. I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.0 on Windows 7. With Visual Studio, I have a *solution* with *projects* underneath. With Netbeans, I appear to just have a *project* with directories determining the rest of the structure (and the IDE to some degree)? The equivalent to `Add Reference` appears to be adding a source to the `Classpath`. There also seems to be a degree of separation between the compiler and the IDE. I'm currently in a situation where I can compile my project just fine while the IDE tells me I still have errors (and I assume this is because I have the project set up incorrectly).

I'm basically looking for analogies that will help me better understand Java project structure.

Comment: If you're totally new to Java, I would recommend starting off with a text editor (just type your source code, name the file MyClass.java, and save it in a directory corresponding to the package name) and using javac on the command line to compile it. After you are comfortable with this, any of the various Java IDEs will make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of similarities between the two languages and IDEs.  I spent many years in both.  For starters the equivalent to 'add reference' in VS is adding a library or jar in netbeans.  In respect to a reference - a jar is pretty much the same thing as a module or .dll in VS.  A jar is a compiled reference. To add a reference just go to the project menu and then properties then to the libraries menu from there you can add either pre-assembled netbeans libraries, which are collections of .jar's, or a single .jar, or even a project.  Once you add a reference you can import them into your class just like you would in C#.

Netbeans doesn't really have a 'solution' as VS does.  You deal with individual projects.  It does however have the capability to add a project as a reference so you don't have to continually re-build the references when you change something between multiple projects.  It also has project groups to group similar projects.

Lastly Apache ANT is responsible for tying everything together in the background.  Netbeans creates a build.xml and build-impl.xml file in the background to tell ANT how to assemble the project into a .jar.

There are my other things to cover but I thing this answers most of your questions.  Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for NetBeans, as I use Eclipse, but you are on the right track with classpath being roughly equivalent to references in the Visual Studio world. Libraries (usually .jar files) are placed on the classpath and must be there both at compile time and runtime (you specify the classpath to the compiler at compile time, and to the JVM at runtime). The classpath can contain many different entries, and they can be anywhere in the project structure (or outside of it entirely).

Java itself doesn't impose many restrictions on your project structure, although various IDEs and build tools do. The one thing that is a universal restriction in all Java environments is that source files (and class files) are placed in a directory named after the package name. So if your package name is com.test.something, then your source files will be in SRC_DIR/com/test/something, and your class files in OUT_DIR/com/test/something (note: SRC_DIR and OUT_DIR are not special variables; each IDE will have a different way to specify those directories).

Java libraires tend to heavily build-on one-another, so at some point, you'll find that the classpath entries are too many to manage manually. Before you get there, you'll want to take a look at [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which are dependency management tools. You'll need to understand how they work (either one, not both) and how to integrate them with your IDE. If you use Eclipse and Maven, m2eclipse offers fairly complete integration between the IDE and the dependency management tool.

Comment: Nice write up @TTar.  You added somethings I left out in mine.  I would stay away from Maven or Ivy in Netbeans as a starter.  I agree they are good tools but the support is kinda klunky in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

> With Netbeans, I appear to just have a
>   project with directories determining
>   the rest of the structure (and the IDE
>   to some degree)?

Visual Studio dictates a particular project layout and since the compiler is so tightly integrated into the IDE there's no real concept of a build script. In contrast, Java has no such structure (although certain 'best practices' have emerged such as having a 'src' directory for source files, 'lib' for libraries, 'test' for test source, etc.) and a build script is usually required to tell the compiler were to find source files and libraries, what artefacts to produce and a miscellany of other chores (running tests, deployment, creating code metrics and so forth).

In simple cases, the IDE will take care of this for you (if you follow the convention for that particular IDE) but ultimately you will probably want to take a look at a build tool to understand what's going on behind the scenes. Apache Ant and Apache Maven are both prominent offerings. Ant is very flexible whereas Maven attempts to dictate a common layout. I suggest you investigate both and see which suits.

> There also seems to be a degree of
>   separation between the compiler and
>   the IDE. I'm currently in a situation
>   where I can compile my project just
>   fine while the IDE tells me I still
>   have errors

If your code compiles, it is correct. The IDE is simply acting in an advisory capacity (and will highlight issues beyond compiler errors, such as warning you of potential code mistakes or bad practice).

> and I assume this is because I have
>   the project set up incorrectly

This is a possibility although, as stated above, there are many other explanations.

Comment: "the compiler is so tightly integrated into the IDE there's no real concept of a build script" - this is complete nonsense. The C# compiler is completely independent of any IDE and the Visual Studio project format *is* an MSBuild build script.